# How do I build project files and packages for Borland C++ Builder 5 from the command line?

Tags: command-line, c++builder

How do I build Borland C++ project files (bpr) and package files (bpk) from the command line?  Project groups (bpg) are apparently make files and can be compile with make.  But bpks and bprs are xml based and the Export to Makefile won't compile with make.
If I put a project in a bpg, make can't seem to find any of the files specified in the bpg since they all appear to be relative references.  I changed the references to absolutes and make reports:
    Fatal: Unable to open makefile

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to directly compile a bpr. Just create a bpk which just includes that single bpr, and you can use make to compile it.

```
"c:\program files\borland\cbuilder5\bin\make" -B -s -fabc.bpg
```

If you also have other borland compilers installed, do not call the make.exe from the other compiler.

EDIT: execute the make command in the directory where the bpg and bpr is located.

Answer (score 1):

Using bpr2mak and make works for me just fine, so as Roger said, you need to give details on what errors you're getting.  BPK files can also be processed with bpr2mak.  I'm using this method to compile a large project with many components, without difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give some more information on 'won't compile'. 
I.e. What error messages are you getting.

One frequent problem the come up with make is addressed at the following

http://www.delphigroups.info/3/8/36427.html